# Tweepy: Search Tweets by Hashtag between two Dates

Tags: python, date, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to scrape tweets related to USA election in 2020. I have the following code:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 12)

df = pd.DataFrame()
tweets = []

q_ = f"#USAElections2020 since:{start_date} until:{end_date}"

for status in Cursor(api.search, q = q_, lang = "en").items():
  tweets.append(status)
```

The list **tweets** is always empty. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Searching between 2 timestamps was removed. You can use the until parameter

```
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                               q=search_query, 
                               lang="en",
                               until=date # format YYYY-MM-DD in datetime. Not string. Twitter only extract tweets before that date
                               ).items(count)
```